# Standard endgame chess positions which are helpful to learn

Tags: endgame

Is there a list of standard endgame chess positions which a player can benefit from learning? By this I mean that any player should know how to play **KQ vs K**, **KR vs B**, **KP vs K** (win if it winnable and draw when it is not).

Then it goes **KBB vs K**, **KRP vs KR** and then on higher level **KQ vs KR**, **KR vs KN**, **KBN vs K**. These are just some of the end-game positions which might be helpful to learn.

Do you have other positions which could be helpful (and may be approximate level when it makes sense to learn them)?

Comment: It probably depends on your level, but I'd say that mastering a variety of KPP vs. KP is vastly, vastly more important than, e.g.,  KBB vs. K.  It would be nice to see an answer backed up with data on how frequently given endgames arise at different levels.

Comment: There's axtually a pretty good book based on this theme called "Silman's complete endgame course", which orders the endgames according to "difficulty level" instead of piece configurations. Other than that, there are some standard endgame positions players should know about, like the Lucena and Philidor positions in rook endgames.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [(practical) Endgame resources: What's next after josh waitzkin's series in chessmaster?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/35641/practical-endgame-resources-whats-next-after-josh-waitzkins-series-in-chess)

Answer (score 3):

For sure **KP** mixes like **KP** vs **KP**, **KPP** vs **KP** etc: learn to count moves to promotion, study opposition and *zugzwang*.

Later **KRP+** mixes: like **KRP** vs **KR** till **KR4P** vs **KR3P** are all quite common, far more relevant than say **KBN** vs **K**, not easy though, especially 4 vs 3 pawns.

A bit less common KNP+ and **KNB**+. still relevant.

Finally endgames where one side has a piece and the other only pawns: this are quite common at lower levels.